No power on two left switches on 4 gang box after a short-circuit
I'm replacing four switches with new smart switches, and while the power was on, the hot wire on the third switch accidentally touched the ground on the first one.
This caused a loud pop and the power going off. The breaker was in the middle position so I first turned it off then back on.
I am unable to get the two left switches to work. The voltage tester does not detect any current on the wires now either, leading me to believe it's not a problem with the switches.
How can I diagnose what's going on?


Possible another breaker is tripped.  Just because 4 switches are in the same box, does not mean they are all on the same circuit.

@crip659 I didn't notice any other breakers tripped on the panel. Would the fact there's no voltage detected from the wires mean anything?

It means a tripped breaker or a bad connection.  Remember what happen when working with the power on.  Next time it will be your fingers making contact with the hot wire and the breaker might not trip as fast.  Might also be a GFCI receptacle on the circuit tripped.

You have one or more of:

Connection that came apart due to the short
Switch that "fried" due to the short
Something miswired - i.e., that had not been tested prior to the short so that they are unrelated

The way to do this is to identify every single wire. Yes, that's a pain. But that's the way to do it. Slow and methodical. Disconnect every wire from the non-functioning switches. Trace out where everything goes - back to the panel, to another switch, to another room, to a switched light, etc.
As part of that process, you should figure out where incoming always hot ("line") power comes from for each switch. Spread out the wires for safety and turn the breaker on. If that wire doesn't have power (in a careful test) then you have to work backwards. If that wire comes from another location, it is possible that a short overloaded a marginal connection (loose wire nut or a backstab) in another box.
